# Yii Migration Runs Successfully, But Results Are Partial

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, database-migration

I wrote a particularly long migration for my website, and unfortunately was caught altering it quite a bit (I know I'm supposed to write additional migrations, instead of altering preexisting ones, but this wasn't possible in this case).

This is a complex migration, so I wrote it into the safeUp() function, as it should be wrapped in a transaction.  When I run the migration, everything seems to work perfectly. It shows me each SQL command as it runs, and then at the end, says it ran successfully.  The migration appears correctly in the history. However, when I visit the database, I realize that the migration **is only partially done.** Which should be impossible because it was written in safeUp().

It should be noted that I was running many migrations at once, and that each one runs successfully. The only time I got it to work, I ran every other migration up until the one in question (using ./yiic migrate to *timestamp*), and then copy pasted the sql into phpmyadmin, and ran it manually.  Boom, perfectly done.

Anyone run into this problem?

-- Edit: I believe the issue here was that Yii parses SQL comments in an interesting way when it runs inside the `$this->execute('sql')`, so that the SQL it was generating was not identical to the raw SQL.

-- Edit2: This is ages ago now, but I'm now learning about this bug https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9894. I think it may apply to Yii1 as well, if anyone out there is reading this.

Comment: MySQL does not support altering schema in transactions. Hence `safeUp` and `up` have no difference.
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/805

Comment: Thanks @German! Actually never considered that but it makes sense.  Can you think of any reason that the migration would run with no errors? And behave differently than the raw sql?